# Reversing an array in Python

Tags: python, array, python-2.x, reinventing-the-wheel

Reversing an array in Python without using a built-in function:

```
def reverse(alist):
    end = len(alist)-1
    limit = int(end/2) + 1
    for i in range(limit):
        alist[i],alist[end] = alist[end],alist[i]
        end = end - 1
    return alist

print reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: One small question: Do you consider slices as being built-ins ? Or are you strictly speaking about the `reversed()` built-in ? If not, you could do `def reverse(alist): return alist[::-1]`

Comment: @Dex'ter Yes, i am considering slice as built-ins here, also alist[::-1].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first solution that comes to mind is to take advantage of the powerful list comprehension and *abuse* the `xrange` function:

```
def reverse(some_list):
    return [some_list[n] for n in xrange(len(some_list) - 1, -1, -1)]
```

The above is nothing more than the usual reversed for loop that you may find in other languages (like C / C++) as:

```
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)  
{  
    // Do something ...  
}
```

Details about the `range` function can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) but basically, all you have to know about it is its prototype:

> `range(start, stop[, step])`

which is very descriptive.

I'd go with this instead of your solution because it looks cleaner and I don't see any reasons of why it'd be slower or harder to understand.

Comment: Why not `xrange`?

Comment: @MrGrj xrange returns an iterable rather than building a list. It would function perfectly in your example, and would mean you had about half the memory usage for larger lists.

Comment: I forgot it had Python 2.x tag ^_^. Hehe

Answer (score 9):

Calculating the `limit` is a tad annoying, because you have to carefully verify to not make an off-by-one error. It would be easier to loop until the indexes cross each other:

```
def reverse(alist):
    left = 0
    right = len(alist) - 1
    while left < right:
        alist[left], alist[right] = alist[right], alist[left]
        left += 1
        right -= 1
```

I made some other changes as well:

- Adjusted formatting to follow [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- I renamed the index variables to more natural `left`, `right`
- I dropped the `return` statement, because it might mislead users to assume that the returned list is a new list, which is not the case, because the function modifies the content of the input list.

Answer (score 3):

Few stylistic points about your current solution:

- use `print()` as a *function* for Python 3 compatibility
- on the other hand, because you are running it on Python 2.x, you may avoid creating an extra list with `range()` and use `xrange()` function ([differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range))
- according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), you need to have spaces around the operators
- you can use `end -= 1` shortcut instead of `end = end - 1`

The code with all the proposed changes applied:

```
def reverse(alist):
    end = len(alist) - 1
    limit = int(end / 2) + 1
    for i in xrange(limit):
        alist[i], alist[end] = alist[end], alist[i]
        end -= 1
    return alist

print(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Note that you don't have to return the `alist` from the function, since your reverse operates "in-place" - it modifies the input list. In other words, if you would remove `return alist` and run:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
reverse(l)
print(l)
```

You would see `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` printed.

---

One more way to do the reverse "manually" can be to use the negative indexing (not sure if it fits your constraints):

```
def reverse(alist):
    return [alist[-i] for i in range(1, len(alist) + 1)]
```

Or, an expanded version without a list comprehension:

```
def reverse(alist):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(1, len(alist) + 1):
        newlist.append(alist[-i])
    return newlist
```

Note that this is not working in place, it would return a *new list*.

Answer (score 2):

Variation of shortest version in @alecxe's answer: since you want `answer[i]` to be `alist[len(alist) - 1 - i] = alist[-1 - i] = alist[~i]`:

```
def reverse(alist):
    return [alist[~i] for i in xrange(len(alist))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming modifying in place is desired, negative indexing can be quite helpful:

```
def reverse(a):
   for i in range(len(a)/2):
      a[i], a[-(i+1)] = a[-(i+1)], a[i]
```

and I can ignore the possible off-by-one an odd number causes because all that will change is whether the center number will swap with itself.

Comment: You can use `~i` rather than `-(i + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another short version:

```
def reverse(l):
    return [l.pop() for _ in range(len(l))]
```

`pop` removes the last item from a list and returns it.
The original list will be emptied by this function:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2]
>>> reverse(l)
[2, 1, 0]
>>> l
[]
```

Comment: This is a strong constraint to have a function that both modifies the input list in place and produce a new list. What if I want to `zip(l, reverse(l))`? Now I can't.